# Group and count items in a collection based on their value

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-collection

I have the following collection:

```
0 => "15.00",
1 => "25.00",
2 => "500.00",
3 => "19.00",
4 => "123.00",
...
```

I want to somehow get the count of all values between 0 and 99, between 100 and 199, between 200 and 299, etc until the max amount.

Some collections might be up to 300 and some might be up to 1000. They still need to be counted by groups of 100.

Comment: What have you tried already?

Comment: Can you share the Model name? and the structure of the table you need to query?

Comment: @MEDZ this comes after some json_decode acrobatics on JSON properties of another collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `mapToGroup` method and use division to create groups. Then sum it separately.

```
$grouped = $collection->mapToGroups(function ($item, $key) {
    return [floor($item / 100) => $item];
});
```

Also you could resign from using Collection methods and make it using pure PHP.

```
$grouped = [];
foreach($array as $item) {
    $grouped[floor($item / 100)][] = $item;
}
```

After that simply use `array_sum()`

Comment: This groups it in a very weird way, e.g. creates a group called "1" and puts all the 1 amounts there, and then creates a group called "99" and puts amounts like "1499" in there.

Comment: I fixed the code in my answer, the correct operation is to divide values by 100.